# Is there a Trigger option in GAE like in apps scripts?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-apps-script

In Google Apps Script there is an trigger option where you can make a function run from a timer without any user input. Is there anything like that for Google App Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scheduled tasks](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron) allow you to define tasks to execute at specified times.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Would these scheduled tasks use the front-end instance like normal? Or use the backend instances instead.

Comment: Its all on the official docs. Take a look there first they explain this well.